# Find number by specific mask in large list

Tags: php, regex

I have a large list with numbers.

How can I find numbers for a specific mask? `(Regex + PHP)`

Example required mask **`AA* ХY YХ`**

```
118 75 57 - Ok
559 93 39 - Ok
777 25 56 - No
808 44 55 - No
```

`A,X,Y,*` - any number `0-9`

Length of the number is always 7 characters.

Comment: Show what you have tried already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make yourself comfortable with i.e. (named/unnamed) backreferences:

```
^                      # start of the string
(?P<A>\d)\g{A}\d\s+    # AA*, whitespaces
(?P<X>\d)(?P<Y>\d)\s+  # XY, whitespaces
\g{Y}\g{X}             # YX
$                      # end of the string
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vOH4lO/2) (and mind the different modifiers, e.g. verbose and multiline).

---

In `PHP`:

```
<?php

$data = [
'118 75 57',
'559 93 39',
'777 25 56',
'808 44 55'
];

$regex = '~
        ^                      # start of the string
        (?P<A>\d)\g{A}\d\s+    # AA*, whitespaces
        (?P<X>\d)(?P<Y>\d)\s+  # XY, whitespaces
        \g{Y}\g{X}             # YX
        $                      # end of the string
~x';

foreach ($data as $item) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $item)) {
        echo "{$item} is valid\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, this would be accomplished like so:

```
<?php

$data = [
'118 75 57',
'559 93 39',
'777 25 56',
'808 44 55'
];
$regex = '/(\d)\1\d (\d)(\d) \3\2/';
foreach($data as $str)
{
    echo preg_match($regex,$str) ? 'matched' : 'not matched',"<br>\n";
}
```